# Error when adding days to date time in windows form C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to add a renewal system where the user can request for extra days. I've tried to layout a a method which will take the value from a combobox and then add that value in days to the current expiry date.

As can be seen in the screen shot below, I'm having an error when trying to add days onto an existing date. I tried various SqlDbTypes including datetime with no success, maybe this isn't the best way to convert the value to days in terms of SQL?

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Well, the amount of days is a number, so why not make the type a number?

Comment: By the way, next time, please show your work and exception message as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

[`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function takes `int` as a second parameter. But you try to add your `@days` parameter with `SqlDbType.VarChar` type.

Add this parameter value as an `SqlDbType.Int` and parse your `cboDays.Text` to integer. For example;

```
com.Parameters.Add("@days", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(cboDays.Text);
```

Also your `UserID` seems like a numeric column typed since it ends with `ID`. In this case, `VarChar` type does not fit for this column.

Comment: worked! i guess that what happens when i only get 2 hours sleep, rookie mistake ha thanks!

Comment: @goldeneye Gald to help.